# Change UITextField background when editing begins

Tags: iphone, objective-c, first-responder

I'd like to change the background image of a UITextField when it becomes the firstResponder to show the user that it has focus, similar to the :active or :focus pseudo-classes in CSS.

I'm guessing that I may need to do this programmatically; so any help is greatly appreciated.

-Giles

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You might as well use the UITextFieldDelegate methods (IMHO, easier to maintain than key-value observers):

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITextFieldDelegate methods

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    _field.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"focus.png"];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    _field.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nofocus.png"];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

This only works when the UITextField.borderStyle property is of any type but UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect (in that case, the background property is not taken into account). This means you might use the code above with UITextBorderStyleBezel, UITextBorderStyleLine and UITextBorderStyleNone, as explained in the borderStyle documentation:

> borderStyle
>
> The border style used by the text field.
>
> @property(nonatomic) UITextBorderStyle borderStyle
>
> Discussion
>
> The default value for this property is
>   UITextBorderStyleNone. If a custom
>   background image is set, this property
>   is ignored.

This is the documentation for the background property of UITextField:

> background
>
> The image that represents the
>   background appearance of the text
>   field when it is enabled.
>
> @property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage
>   *background
>
> Discussion
>
> When set, the image referred to by
>   this property replaces the standard
>   appearance controlled by the
>   borderStyle property. Background
>   images are drawn in the border
>   rectangle portion of the image. Images
>   you use for the text field’s
>   background should be able to stretch
>   to fit.

Comment: thanks for mentioning about the borderStyle. This should be mentioned in the documentation for the background property of UITextField

Comment: I have found a mistake in your text. if UITextField is with rounded angles then it ignores all the background images. Not vice versa

Answer (score 29):

The cleanest way IMHO is to subclass `UITextField` and override `becomeFirstResponder` and `resignFirstResponder` to change the background image of the text field. That way, you can use your new subclass anywhere without having to reimplement the delegate methods to change the background.

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
    BOOL outcome = [super becomeFirstResponder];
    if (outcome) {
      self.background = // selected state image;
    }
    return outcome;
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder {
    BOOL outcome = [super resignFirstResponder];
    if (outcome) {
      self.background = // normal state image;
    }
    return outcome;
}
```

Comment: Cleanest is subjective, proponents of composition have different taste of cleanest solution.

Answer (score 3):

**SWIFT 4**

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(anyFunction), for: UIControlEvents.editingDidBegin)


@objc func anyFunction() {
    // Add your conde here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try observing for changes to isFirstResponder. and changing the background in the notification method. Something like:

```
[textField addObserver:theObserver forKeyPath:@"isFirstResponder" options:0 context:nil];
```

Then in the observer:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if(object == textField && [keyPath isEqual:@"isFirstResponder"]) {
        //fiddle with object here
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to check when it becomes firstResponder but how do I actually change the background image?

Comment: you can change the layer contents of the textField to a CGImage
textField.layer.contents = myImage.CGImage;

should work.