# perform an action after textfield selected by user?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

(Iphone app) i would like to send one message after user select textfield, in that textfield only. but when ever we click on textfield keyboard appears.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change UITextField background when editing begins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993598/change-uitextfield-background-when-editing-begins)

Answer (score 1):

Set the delegate of the `UITextField` and implement this method in the delegate:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Do whatever you want

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Let them new user search first, begin a responsible stack member you should not do this.

Comment: This answer is not wrong and doesn't deserve a downvote just because you didn't like the question!

Answer (score -1):

Add `UITextFieldDelegate` in `.h` file and in `.m` file set Your `yourTextField.delegate = self;` and write this bellow code..

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // write your messagehere
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: up vote for correct answer. @Pritam I understand your point, but understand the community of stack overflow is full of helpful people. Please don't bark them away for trying to help.

Comment: you are right @Freddy and so i post this answer.. because this is not illegal or out of subject quetion so i post the answer.. :)